# How to refactor a vector?

Tags: r

I have this vector

```
v <- c("firstOne","firstTwo","secondOne")
```

I would like to factor the vector assigning `c("firstOne","firstTwo)` to the same level (i.e., `firstOne`). I have tried this:

```
> factor(v, labels = c("firstOne", "firstOne", "secondOne"))
[1] firstOne  firstOne  secondOne
Levels: firstOne firstOne secondOne
```

But I get a duplicate factor (and a warning message advising not to use it). Instead, I would like the output to look like:

```
[1] firstOne  firstOne      secondOne
Levels: firstOne secondOne
```

Is there any way to get this output without brutally substituting the character strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I also found a solution which looks somehow sloppy but I don't see major issues (looking forward to listen which might be possible problems with this tho):

```
v <- c("firstOne","firstTwo","secondOne")
factor(v)
factor(factor(v,labels = c("firstOne","firstOne","secondOne")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of options:

```
v <- factor(ifelse(v %in% c("firstOne", "firstTwo"), "firstOne", "secondOne"))
v <- factor(v,levels = c("firstOne","secondOne")); f[is.na(f)] <- 'firstOne'
```

Answer (score 2):

A factor is just a numeric (integer) vector with labels, and so manipulating a factor is equivalent to manipulating integers, rather than character strings. Therefore performance-wise is perfectly OK to do

```
f <- as.factor(v)
f[f %in% c('firstOne', 'firstTwo')] <- 'firstOne'
f <- droplevels(f)
```

Comment: Assign to the levels instead and then you're done. `levels(f)[levels(f) %in% c("firstOne","firstTwo")] <- "firstOne"`

Comment: @thelatemail i didn't know this was possible, but it is

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `rec`-function of the [sjmisc-package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc):

```
rec(v, "firstTwo=firstOne;else=copy", as.fac = T)

> [1] firstOne  firstOne  secondOne
> Levels: firstOne secondOne
```

(the output is shortened; note that the sjmisc-package supports [labelled data](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjmisc/) and thus adds label attributes to the vector, which you'll see in the console output as well)